# How to use EntityState for related tables (FK) in Entity Framework 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Consider the following table

**Table 1 : Employee**

- Id
- Name
- Email

**Table 2 : Vehicle**

- Id
- EmployeeId
- VehicleId

*An Employee can have multiple Vehicle.*

Now based on some condition I want to not allow user to update the `employee` table and `vehicle` table.

So for this, for the `employee` table I use

```
var emp = appContext.Employee.Find(empId);

// some update code goes here

if(someCondition(userId))
  appContext.Entry(emp).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```

This works fine.

Now how do I do the same for the related `Vehicle` table ?

**Update 1**

I tried this and it did not work

```
appContext.Entry(emp).Collection(r => r.Vehicle).EntityEntry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```

Comment: I dont want to allow users to update a table, if they do not have access to do so. They may have create access but not edit access also this example is only for representation. There are many related tables in my case and I want user to update only allowed tables in his case.

Comment: So you want to update part of the graph or not update at all depending on some logic? And do you get yhe updates from the client?

Comment: @Omar.Alani Both, depending on what my permission module says, I may want to prevent updating the whole related graph object or only prevent update of some properties of the related graph object.
For eg. I may prevent updation of whole Vehile realtion or only prevent update to some properties of Vehicle object.
Yes I get updates from client so that is why I want to revert Sate on properties which the client does not have permission.

Comment: I assume that you receive a DTO object from the client and one way to achieve what you need is through automapper where you can ignore some properties or subentities depending on the business logic that you have. Look at http://automapper.org/.